# INeedInitialization or IConfigureThisEndpoint, which one to use?

Tags: configuration, nservicebus

I know we can implement IWantCustomInitialization  to configure NServicebus with other IoC continers lets say Castle.Windsor for instance, but I found this is obsoleted.  in new version alternatively  I used INeedInitialization, but it also  didn't solve my issue because the container was specified before "INeedInitialization.Customize" invocation, So 
at last I implemented IConfigureThisEndpoint as my final solution.

To sum up my question; when to use "INeedInitialization" and "IConfigureThisEndpoint"?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been changed a bit over time and v5 of NServiceBus [introduce a different API](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgradeguides/4to5).  For context you can [read through the following bug comments](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2240).  What the intent is:

- **IConfigureThisEndpoint** - for configuring the Endpoint.  Can only have 1 per instance.
- **INeedInitialization** - for configuring a component used by the Endpoint.  Can have multiple implementations of this per instance.

An example of when to use **IConfigureThisEndpoint** ([see full example](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Msmq.Samples/blob/master/VideoStore.Msmq/VideoStore.ContentManagement/EndpointConfig.cs))

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, UsingTransport<MsmqTransport>
    {
        public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {
            configuration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>();               
        }
    }
```

An example of when to use **INeedInitialization** ([see full example](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Msmq.Samples/blob/335c04d451256da897ecb7aae8c2a7d9ea461c10/Gateway/SiteA/ResponderInstaller.cs))

```
class ResponderInstaller : INeedInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<CustomHttpResponder>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
        }
    }
```

Comment: edit: sorry, provided a bad example for INeedInitialization on first go

Answer (score 1):

Both give you access to do basically the same things. The big difference is that `IConfigureThisEndpoint` is once per endpoint, so you use that to configure truly endpoint-specific things. `INeedInitialization` can have many implementations, and all of them get executed. So you can package up multiple `INeedInitialization` behaviors in a Conventions assembly and use them throughout your solution to carry out tasks common to multiple (or all) endpoints.